# Class not found, Laravel Observer

Tags: php, exception, upgrade, laravel-5, observers

I'm in the process of switching from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5, not sure if that is relevant, but I am getting an error:

```
"Class 'library\observers\UserObserver' not found"
```

and I have no Idea what the problem is, as far as I can see ( through my frustration mind you ) is that everything is in its right place, name spaces, folders, class names etc.. and I've ran the artisan dump autoload command twice now. the class is an observer which modifies user input on save. here is my code:

UserObserverServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use library\observers\UserObserver;
use App\Models\User;

class UserObserverServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe( new UserObserver );
    }
    public function register(){}
}
```

UserObserver.php:

```
<?php namespace library\observers;

use library\Facades\Geo;
use Geocode;
use State;
use City;

class UserObserver{ code for user observer }
```

app.php configuration for service provider:

```
        'App\providers\UserObserverServiceProvider',
```

All of these things were working together before the switch, what am I missing?

Comment: Where do you have your `UserObserver` class in directory structure? Is it in `\library\observers` directory ?

Comment: as @MarcinNabiałek say, looks like `library\observers\UserObserver` is based in a different folder structure

Comment: the path to the UserObserver class, the file it is in "UserObserver.php" is in: "/app/library/observers/UserObserver.php", thats the copied path

Answer (score 0):

I left the App out of the namespace and path for use, works now, thanks!